# What type of Jquery call would produce a popup similar to what you get from the 'Flag' link?

Tags: jquery, popup

When you click on the Flag link on S.O. it produces some kind of popup.

What kind of jQuery call would produce a similar popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [jQuery UI DIalog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

[jQuery Effects](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects)

Answer (score 0):

A lightweight alternative to jQuery UI's dialogs is [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)